# Why the function useState does not update the value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying on React.js but what I would like does not work. Here is my code :

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'; 
  function App() {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0); 
    setCount(count + 1);
    return (
      <div>
        <p>value of count : {count} fois</p>
      </div>
    );
  }

export default App;
```

I got :

`Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.`

You can see the error there : https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-engelbart-tzbxv?file=/src/App.js:0-244

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You're creating an infinite loop. Every time state updates, the component is re-rendered. The component is rendering, then it's calling `setCount` the state updates, then the component renders, and on and on.

You can use `useEffect` to update the state after it's rendered the first time.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setCount(count + 1)
},[])
```

I'm not sure what the point of this would be though, since you can just pass the initial value into `useState`

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `setCount` in the body of the component, which is essentially the render function if thinking in a class based component. Therefore it is causing an infinite loop of setting a new value, rerender, setting a new value, rerender, and so on.

You should only be calling `setCount` from some sort of event, e.g. a button click or an effect, e.g. using `useEffect`

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you change the state then rerender is triggered.

In your case, when you are calling `setCount` on the `count` and the `count` state is changing and it is triggering rerender and this cycle is continued. That's why this error.

Try this example, where the `setCount` is called when only once and the value is being changed as it supposed to be.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    setCount(count + 1);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <p>value of count : {count} fois</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is another example where `count` is increased every time the button is pressed:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    setCount(count + 1);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <p>value of count : {count} fois</p>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setCount(count + 1);
        }}
      >
        Increase
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Output:**

[image]

[Codesandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-wildflower-yr585?file=/src/App.js:0-390)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the error is that calling `setCount(count + 1);` will increase the state count forever. Try putting it on a condition, for example in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-cdn-1r8yg?file=/src/App.js:0-343)/code below, the state count is increased by 1 every time you click the button. You could also increase state `if (count < 10)`, inside of a `setInterval` or under a wide variety of conditions. Just not infinitely! ;)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const increaseCount = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>value of count : {count} fois</p>
      <button onClick={increaseCount}>start count</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```